# Running .NET COM assembly from Python. Python path for Assembly dlls?

Tags: c#, python, .net, com

I am running a .NET COM assembly from Python and can only get this working when I copy the assembly dll and dependencies to my Python root path c:\Python27.

This is untidy and so I'd like to have the dlls located in my module installation directory.

Does anyone know how to point python to a different location to pick up dlls? Specifically a COM dll and its dependencies.

I have tried

```
sys.path.append("C:\\Python27\\Lib\\site-packages\\mymodule")
```

But this makes no difference. The python exe only looks for the files in c:\python27.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

For future readers, make sure that you:

1. Register assembly correctly via regasm, i.e. `regasm /tlb /codebase Assembly.dll`
2. Make sure that assembly was registered successfully via PythonWin→Tools→Com Browser→Registered Type Libraries
3. Register (make wrapper) of your COM to be accessible from python via PythonWin→Tools→COM Makepy

Here you are, it can be located wherever you want.